# How to select Excel range in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the following code in a function:

```
function Excel2PPT{


param ($xslx, $targetsheet, $targetrange, $pptx, $targetslide, $npath)
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($xslx)
    $Excel.Visible= $true
    $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item($targetsheet)

$range = $worksheet.Range($targetrange)
$range.select()
$range.copy()
```

I am using it in another function which passes to it "A1:O12" as $targetrange

This worked in previous testing but now yields an error and unexpected behavior.

I reference it as:

```
Excel2PPT $IncomingABCExcel 1 'A1-O12' $testPPT2 $Targetslide $testPPT3
```

The error is:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At C:\...\Excel2PPT.ps1:16 char:1
+ $range = $worksheet.Range($targetrange)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\...\Excel2PPT.ps1:17 char:1
+ $range.select()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\...\Excel2PPT.ps1:18 char:1
+ $range.copy()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

What can I do to fix it? It should be copying and pasting $targetrange to the intended PPT slide but it appears to be copying and pasting "$IncomingABCExcel" (not the variable, the variable name) onto the slide.

Comment: Where are you defining `$targetrange`? and have you checked if it is NULL?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Can you print the value of `$targetRange` prior to line 16 `$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item($targetsheet)` ?

Comment: I tried and it appears to be null, which matches the behavior but that's so odd. Am I not passing it in correctly?

Comment: It could be that you are not passing to the function correctly or that you have not assigned a value to the variable beforehand, just print the value of it before the function call. If it prints then you know it is in the function call.

Comment: I tried playing around with passing it using single or double quotes. Now it prints target range but it still yields the same error and similar wrong behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are using 'A1-012' As the range. This should be 'A1:012':

```
function Excel2PPT {
    param ($xslx, $targetsheet, $targetrange, $pptx, $targetslide, $npath)

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($xslx)
    $Excel.Visible= $true
    $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item($targetsheet)
    $range = $worksheet.Range($targetrange)
    $range.select()
    $range.copy()
}

Excel2PPT $IncomingABCExcel 1 'A1:O12' $testPPT2 $Targetslide $testPPT3
```